# Xamarin Forms Custom Control only Notify Model on change ItemSelected

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

Hi guys I am having some problems in my Xamarin Forms Project, in my app, a ListView show many row of data in columns (500++), the Xamarin Forms ListView rendering was so slow (and consuming ram in scroll), then I create a Custom Control to use a native ListView, it was very helpful and now the rendering speed is not a problem(also the ram consumo in scroll is not a problem).

But the use of this method have a problem, now when I edit a textbox embedded in a row of the listview, the property on the model is not notified but only is notificated when I change the ItemSelected.

// My Custom Control

```
public class NativeListView : ListView
    {
        public NativeListView()
        {
        }
    }
```

// My Custom Control Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeListView), typeof(NativeListViewRenderer))]
namespace AppName.UWP.NativeCode.CustomControlsRenderers
{
  public  class NativeListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control is ListView listView)
            {
                listView.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["NativeListViewItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// My DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NativeListViewItemTemplate">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                             Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Text="{Binding Validate}"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

// My Page XAML

```
<customcontrols:NativeListView
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding NativeListView_ItemsSource}"/>
```

// My PageViewModel

```
public class Model : BindableBase
        {
            private string _value;
            public string Value
            {
                get { return _value; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _value, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Validate))); }
            }

            public string Validate
            {
                get
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
                    {
                        return "❌";
                    }
                    return "✔";
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Model> nativeListView_ItemsSource;
        public ObservableCollection<Model> NativeListView_ItemsSource
        {
            get { return nativeListView_ItemsSource; }
            set { SetProperty(ref nativeListView_ItemsSource, value); }
        }
```

// Ctor:

```
NativeListView_ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Model>
            {
                new Model(){Value="8"},new Model(){Value="1"},new Model(){Value=""},
                new Model(){Value="6"},new Model(){Value=""},new Model(){Value="4"},
                new Model(){Value="7"},new Model(){Value="5"},new Model(){Value="7"},
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely be interested in the original setup, because I don't think Xamarin.Forms `DataTemplate` should cause any performance issues, especially on UWP, so definitely feel free to share the original code as well.

However in this case in UWP the property change notification in `TextBox` happens only after the control loses focus. If you want to make the notification happen after each keystroke, you need to edit the `Binding` as follows:

```
 Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Many thank, it solved my problem. The performance of the app was like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oPWmvWHYA4 , my datatemplate have horizontal and vertical plain BoxViews to simulate a cell, then I think  it causes the bad performance in the Xamarin Forms Listview.